# Google Cloud Shell Web Preview with https backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubectl, google-cloud-shell

I have deployed Confluent platform on GCP. We are trying to access control-center using `kubectl port-forward` to 9021 in Google Cloud shell. When I am trying to use Google cloud shell web preview to 9021, I am not able to open as most probably control center exposes https and not http endpoint and web-preview not intelligent to access https backend, but only http endpoint.
Is there anything can be done ?

NB - I cannot open loadbalancer service or ingress to expose control-center in the internet.

Comment: May I know why do you need Cloud Shell for this use case? It's [documented](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview#starting_the_web_application) that only HTTP requests are permitted. Have you tried running the command from your local machine or a VM?

Comment: We are thinking to use cloud-shell so that we don't need to deploy any VM. Plus cloud-shell gives us this webpreview. We thought that can be a secure and easy way to access. There are no problem with port-forward, as we have checked with curl that it works.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone has used inlets, or telepresence for such use cases?

Comment: Why you don't create a port forward on your local environment instead of Cloud Shell?